# Decompress file with wrong size

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method that decompresses *.gz file:

```
using (FileStream originalFileStream = new FileStream(gztempfilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
  using (FileStream decompressedFileStream = new FileStream(outputtempfilename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
  {
    using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(originalFileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
      decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedFileStream);
    }
  }
}
```

It worked perfectly, but recently I received pack of files with wrong size:
When I open them with 7-zip they have *Packed Size* ~ 1,600,000 and *Size* = 7 (it should be ~20,000,000).
[image]
So when I extract them using this code I get only a part of the file. But when I extract this file using 7-zip I get full file.

How can I handle this situation in my code?

Comment: I don't quite get what has the wrong size here. Are the GZip archives smaller than expected? Be aware that the GZip format does not store the original file size as is but [the result of a modulo-division by _2^32_ of it](http://www.zlib.org/rfc-gzip.html).

Comment: I've added a screenshot to make it clear.

Comment: What does it say when you press the light blue "Test" button?

Comment: Folders: 0
Files: 1

There are no errors

Comment: It can be decompressed using 7-zip without problems, but when I decompress it using provided code it decompresses only the part of file

Comment: Probably add a check after the decompression: check the file size, if it is less than expected. `long length = new System.IO.FileInfo(path).Length;`

Comment: What is the exact original file size you expect? You said _~20,000,000_. Can you state that more precisely?

Comment: How much of the file are you able to decompress? Also, is that part correctly decompressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that that the other end does a mistake when GZipping the files. It looks like it does not set the [ISIZE bytes](http://www.zlib.org/rfc-gzip.html) correctly.

The ISIZE bytes are the *last four bytes* of a valid GZip file and come after a 32-bit CRC value which in turn comes directly after the compressed data bytes.

7-Zip seems to be robust against such mistakes whereas the `GZipStream` is not. It is odd however that 7-Zip is not showing you any errors. It should show you (tested with 7-Zip 16.02 x64/Win7)...

- CRC error in case the size is simply wrong,
- "Unexpected end of data" in case some or all of the ISIZE bytes are cut off,
- "There are some data after end of the payload data" in case there is more data following the ISIZE bytes.

7-Zip always uses the last four bytes of the packed file to determine the size of the original unpacked file without checking if the file is valid and whether the bytes read for that are actually the ISIZE bytes.

You can verify this by checking those last four bytes of the GZipped file with a hex viewer. For your example they should be exactly `07 00 00 00`.

If you know the exact size of the unpacked original file you could replace those bytes so that they specify the correct size. For instance, if the unpacked file's size is *20,000,078*, which is *01312D4E* in hex (*0*-padded to eight digits), those bytes should be `4E 2D 31 01`.

In case you don't know the exact size you can try replacing them with the maximum value, i.e. `FF FF FF FF`.

After that try your unpack code again.

This is obviously only a hacky solution to your problem. Better try fixing the code that GZips the files you receive or try to find a library that is more robust than `GZipStream`.

Comment: I've tried to replace 07 00 00 00 bytes to FF FF FF FF and in 7zip file manager size was displayed like 4,294,967,295. But I still has the same problem when i try to decompress this file using my code. Also, when I changed this last bytes i got a "CRC failed" error when I was trying to decompress it using 7-zip. Now I'm going to use SevenZipExtractor library. May be it'll help

Comment: @Ivan, so your code never throws an `InvalidDataException`? Even after you changed the ISIZE bytes? Have you tried adding a `try-catch` block around your unpack code?

Comment: Yes, It doesn't throws any exceptions. I have large xml file in this archive and it decompress only two first tags.

Comment: @Ivan, interesting. This bug is very intriguing. Is there a possibility I could get hands on that particular GZip file?

Comment: Sorry, but there is some confidential information inside this archives. And I don't know how to remove it and recompress them to reproduce this issue. Thank you for you help, I'll appreciate any new ideas. For now I'll try to contact support of product, which send us this archives

Answer (score 1):

I've used ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip.GZipInputStream from [this](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib) library instead of System.IO.Compression.GZipStream and it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this for check the size? ie:

```
byte[] bArray;
using (FileStream f = new FileStream(tempFile, FileMode.Open))
{
   bArray= new byte[f.Length];
   f.Read(b, 0, f.Length);
}
```

Regards

try:

```
            GZipStream uncompressed = new GZipStream(streamIn, CompressionMode.Decompress, true);
            FileStream streamOut = new FileStream(tempDoc[0], FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
```

Comment: I put breakpoint on the "decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedFileStream);" line and chekced length of all streams. originalFileStream: 1554925; decompressedFileStream: 165 so it seems that it lost somewhere in GZipStream

Comment: I have a process that make the same, the only difference i see are the final values in gzipstream and output fileStream. Try if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is some sort of bug in GZipStream (it does not write original file length into gz end of file).
You need to change the way you compress your files using GZipStream.
The way it will work:

```
            inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output);
            using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(outputStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                    gZipStream.Write(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.Length);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("file.xml.gz", outputStream.ToArray());
            }
```

And this way will cause the error you have (no matter will you use Flush() or not):

```
            inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output);
            using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(outputStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    gZipStream.Write(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.Length);
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("file.xml.gz", outputStream.ToArray());
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to call decompressedStream.Seek() after closing the gZip stream.

As [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58943752/9007125).