# Issues in Compress / Decompress with GZipStream C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Can someone help in understanding what's wrong in below code?
As it shows I am just trying to compress and decompress a memory stream.

```
        //read
            var memStream = new MemoryStream();            
            using (Stream fs = File.Open(@"..\..\..\TextFile.txt", FileMode.Open)) {
                var byteArray = new byte[1 * 1024];
                int len = 0;

                while ((len = fs.Read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)) > 0) {
                    memStream.Write(byteArray, 0, len);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("read bytes {0}",memStream.Length);

            //compress
            byte[] compBytes;
            using (var memStream2 = new MemoryStream()) {
                memStream2.Position = 0;
                using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(memStream2, CompressionMode.Compress)) {
                    memStream.Position = 0;
                     memStream.CopyTo(zipStream);                    
                    compBytes = memStream2.ToArray();
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine("compressed bytes {0}", compBytes.Length);

            //decompress
            byte[] decompBytes;
            using (var memStream3 = new MemoryStream(compBytes)) {
                memStream3.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                using (var memStream4 = new MemoryStream()) {
                    using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(memStream3, CompressionMode.Decompress)) {

                        zipStream.CopyTo(memStream4);
                        decompBytes = memStream4.ToArray();
                    }

                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("decompressed bytes {0}", decompBytes.Length);
```

Output:

read bytes 6034

compressed bytes 10

decompressed bytes 0

Comment: You can simplify your code a bit:
Instead of reading the file in chunks, just use
fs.CopyTo(memStream);

Furthermore after construction a new MemoryStream, you don't need to Seek to the beginning of the stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **must** [Flush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.flush(v=vs.80).aspx) the `GZipStream` or [Dispose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.dispose(v=vs.80).aspx) it before you read the target `MemoryStream`.

Try this:

```
//compress
byte[] compBytes;
using (var memStream2 = new MemoryStream()) {
    memStream2.Position = 0;
    using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(memStream2, CompressionMode.Compress)) {
        memStream.Position = 0;
         memStream.CopyTo(zipStream);  

    }
    compBytes = memStream2.ToArray();  <--- move it out of the zipstream using to flush it.

}
Console.WriteLine("compressed bytes {0}", compBytes.Length);
```

Zip works with blocks and buffers the input. Disposing/flush it will force the zipstream to write a smaller block.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just create 2 function that compresses and decompresses:

```
public static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
{
    MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
    using (DeflateStream dstream = new DeflateStream(output, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
    {
        dstream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
    return output.ToArray();
}

public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] data)
{
    MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(data);
    MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
    using (DeflateStream dstream = new DeflateStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        dstream.CopyTo(output);
    }
    return output.ToArray();
}
```

If you want to compress and decompress a text file use this:

```
string file = File.ReadAllText("TEXT FILE LOCATION HERE");
            byte[] compressed = Compress(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(file));
            byte[] decompressed = Decompress(compressed);
```

Answer (score 0):

It was also important to call `decompressedStream.Seek()` **after** closing the zip stream. Otherwise, the resulting "decompressed" stream was smaller in size than expected.

```
//decompression:

var compressedStream =  new MemoryStream( myByteArray );
var decompressedStream =  new MemoryStream();

var zipStream =  new GZipStream( compressedStream, 
                                 CompressionMode.Decompress, true);  //NOTICE 'true': will close manually, later.

zipStream.CopyTo( decompressedStream ); 
zipStream.Close();
decompressedStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);     //NOTICE THIS LINE, after  .Close()
```

And as others mentioned, after the `.Close()` was called we can access its array, etc:

```
var loadable = myBinaryFormatter.Deserialize(decompressedStream) as MyFancyObject;
decompressedStream.Close();
```