# Gzip: never compress the first byte, but compress the rest?

Tags: c#, compression

I'm trying to compress a large array before sending it via network. However, the first byte must never be compressed.

**Question:**

Using GZip, is there a way to do this efficiently, - without creating an extra MemoryStream after the compression was complete?

During decompression, my plan would be to read the first byte, then treat the rest as a compressed buffer. How to do that?

**My typical workflow:**

```
var compressedStream = new MemoryStream();
var zipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.Optimal, true);
      
var w = new BinaryWriter( zipStream );

byte packetType = 5;
w.Write(packetType);   <-----  gets compressed :( 

while(hasMore){
   w.Write(someVars);
}

//IMPORTANT: close, then Seek()  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58943752/9007125
zipStream.Close();
binaryWriter.Close();
compressedStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Comment: How about `var firstByte = new BinaryWriter( compressedStream ); firstByte .Write(packetType);` ?

Comment: @Magnetron Hm, that should work, except the packetType needs to be at the front... Also, is making additional BinaryWriter relatively efficient?

Comment: You actualy don't need the BinaryWriter, you can call [`WriteByte`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.writebyte?view=net-6.0) from the `compressedStream` for the first byte. To sum up, if you want some data to not be compressed, write them directly to the underlining stream, instead of the GZipStream

Comment: Side note: you really should put the streams in `using` blocks.